# How can I flush a file descriptor returned by pygtk / gnome's gobject.spawn_async

Tags: asynchronous, pygtk, gobject

I use the following calls to spawn a process, get back file descriptors for its stdin, stdout, and stderr, and watch for output on its stdout:

```
[widget.pid,widget.stdin,widget.stdout,widget.stderr] = \
            gobject.spawn_async(['/bin/sed','s/hi/by/g'], 
                                standard_input=True,
                                standard_output=True,
                                standard_error=True
                                )
 gobject.io_add_watch(widget.stdout,
                      gobject.IO_IN,
                      getdata)
```

I then write lines to widget.stdin, expecting to trigger the callback function getdata.

What I find is that the callback getdata is called only when I close widget.stdin.

From the terminal, on the other hand, sed echoes each completed line sent to stdin, and so I expect that sed is generating output whenever it sees a completed line at its stdin and that it just isn't getting the lines one at a time.

I'm not clear on how I can force the lines written to widget.stdin to be seen at /bin/sed, while leaving the connection open to send more lines.  The python -u flag does not seem to make any difference.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have asked the wrong question; I will submit this under a different title.

What I'm finding is that the watch on the child's stdout is only triggered in the parent when the pipe to the child has filled; in other words, it appears that the child (the "sed" process) does not actually receive any input until the pipe has filled.  When I set the pipe size to 4096 and prefill the pipe to the child with 4096 bytes, I can send 512 byte chunks and my parent process' io_add_watch callback, which will read up to 512 bytes, gets called every time I send a new chunk to the child.